# Spring Roo with Java 8

Tags: spring, lambda, parallel-processing, java-stream, roo

Does SpringRoo generate code for Java 8 features: Streams, Lambda, Parallel Processing? If so, please point to example links.

The SpringRoo release notes mention that it supports Java 8, but has no more details.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I was evaluating Spring Roo. There is the 1.x branch which afaik does not have any special support for Java 8 since it was released years ago, and it is a feature of the upcoming 2.x version to support Spring 4 according to [a blog entry from early 2015](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/30/looking-ahead-to-spring-roo-2-0). But there is still no final version available, so possibly this is not a high-priority project.

You might also have a look at Spring Boot. With Spring Boot you can create JPA entities, CRUD repositories and REST interfaces with very little boilerplate code. In my opinion, this reduces the need for a tool such as Spring Roo.